# error Parsing error: Unexpected token : in my .eslintrc.json file. Why?

Tags: json, eslint

this is my code in my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": "latest",
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "rules": {
      "indent": ["error", "tab"],
      "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
      "quotes": ["error", "single"],
      "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
  }
```

this is the error, every time I try to run a commit:

```
PS C:\frontend> git commit -a -m "try"
[STARTED] Preparing lint-staged...
[SUCCESS] Preparing lint-staged...
[STARTED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] package.json — 3 files
[STARTED] **/*.{js,jsx,json} — 1 file
[STARTED] eslint . --fix
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[STARTED] Applying modifications from tasks...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up temporary files...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ eslint . --fix:
Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .

C:\frontend\.eslintrc.json
  3:10  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

can not figure out what is wrong with this line:

```
 "env": {
```

would very much appreciate any suggestions!
thank you!

Comment: This appears to be valid JSON. What command are you running that causes the error?

Comment: git commit -a -m "try"

Comment: Apparently, ESLint tries to lint your JSON files, but to do this you need to use plugins which support parsing of JSON files, it's not supported out of the box. Could you share your husky config? And maybe search your project for occurrences of `**/*.{js,jsx,json}`?

Comment: in my package.json
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,json}": [
      "eslint . --fix"
    ]
  },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to lint a JSON file, but ESLint doesn't support linting of JSON files out of the box. You are left with two options now:

1. If JSON file linting is important to you, you can install and configure a plugin which supports this, such as [eslint-plugin-json](https://github.com/azeemba/eslint-plugin-json)
2. If you don't care about linting your JSON files, remove the `json` extension from your lint script in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint-staged": {
      "**/*.{js,jsx}": [ "eslint . --fix" ]
    }
  }
}
```